# Is it possible to have dead letter queue for individual queues

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I currently have a Queue in my ActiveMQ server called `hello.world`. Whenever a message fails to be processed, ActiveMQ creates a default directory called `ActiveMQ.DLQ`. Is it possible to change that name to something like `hello.world.DLQ`? The reason being is that I might have several queues in the future and I want it to be something like `<queue_name>.DLQ`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called `Individual Dead letter Queue strategy`, 
in this process ActiveMQ creates specific DLQ for each queue/topic,

you can implement it as follows, by tweaking your `activemq.xml` a bit

```
 <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
       <policyEntry queue=">">  <!-- '>' is the wildcard used in ActiveMQ which means for all queues, i.e. same as '*' in any other language -->
        <!-- need to add the following lines in you conf file -->
          <deadLetterStrategy>
            <individualDeadLetterStrategy
              queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
          </deadLetterStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
```

this configuration will create DLQ with names like `DLQ.<queue_name>` , if you do not want the prefix , you can remove `queuePrefix` attribute.

hope this helps!

Good luck!